# Cancel or destroy a looping background thread on viewcontroller close

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to implement an auto save function to my app and having troubles with killing my background loop when the viewcontroller is no longer active.

This is currently what my method looks like:

```
-(void)saveTimer{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:15];
        NSLog(@"saving now");
        [self save:self];
        [self saveTimer];
    });
}
```

I have read a little that I may not be able to cancel a global thread this this so I have also looked at using NSOperationQueue like this:

```
myQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        // Background work

        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            // Main thread work (UI usually)
        }];
    }];
```

But dont know how to cancel or destroy this either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using an NSTimer instead. This way you could fire your timer like this (holding a reference to it):

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:15 target:self selector:@selector(save:self:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

And then, when you want to stop it, just call

```
[timer invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

Comment: I like this approach and it seems to work as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel your operationQueue in -dealloc() method of your viewController. As such:

```
 (void)dealloc {
    [_queue cancelAllOperations];
    [_queue release];
}
```